# Docker, how to add a folder in OS Ubuntu in Container

Tags: docker, containers

I want to add a file in OS ubuntu in Container Docker, how do it so that the file can be entered on the OS ubuntu

```
Docker ~> Container ~> Ubuntu 14.04 ~> upload file in OS Ubuntu 14.04
```

And how to save session container that was run?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to copy a directory from the docker host into the container? Can you copy the directory into the image instead of the container? Do you want to mount a directory from the host into the container?

Comment: Iam sorry, 
In the docker, I want to add files to the "OS Ubuntu 14:04" were added into images, the file was uploaded to the images "OS Ubuntu 14:04", Can it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Docker file with something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

COPY <SRC> <DST IN CONTAINER>
```

Then run:

```
docker build -t mycontainer .
```

Comment: This way if added to Dockerfile?
COPY <SRC> <DST IN CONTAINER>

Comment: Can provide an example to me, how to add a file? From syntax COPY <SRC> <DST IN CONTAINER>

Comment: That's the sample.  SRC can be something `/path/to/my/file` and DST can be `/path/to/my/dst/in/the/container`

Comment: I don't know to add the path <DST IN CONTAINER>
it is in which directory?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto whatever directory you choose in the container!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96510/discussion-between-yudi-dwiyanto-and-rico).